# xml file replace awk

Tags: bash, awk

I need to replace TASKTYPE value just for JOBNAME="NSVN1QU1"

I use this:

```
awk -v jobname="NSVN1QU1" -v tasktype="vvvvvv" '$0 ~ "JOBNAME`enter code here`=\"" jobname "\"" { sub(/TASKTYPE="[^"]*"/, "TASKTYPE=\"" tasktype "\"") } 1' "$out" > "$tmp"
```

Input data:

```
<JOB
    JOBNAME="NSVN1QU1"
    SYSDB="0"
    TASKTYPE="Command"
    USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
    WEEKDAYS="1,2,3,4,5,6">
    <ON AND_OR="A" CODE="NOTOK" STMT="*">
        <DOCOND NAME="ZGIF00P01NSVN1QU1-KO" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
    </ON>
</JOB>
<JOB
    JOBNAME="NSVN1999"
    SYSDB="0"
    TASKTYPE="Dummy"
    USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N"
    <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="ZGIF00P01NSVN1000-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
    <OUTCOND NAME="ZGIF00P01NSVN1999-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
    <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QR-GIF00P000" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
</JOB>
<JOB 
    JOBNAME="NSVN1000"
    SYSDB="0"
    TASKTYPE="Dummy"
    USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N">
    <INCOND AND_OR="A" NAME="ZGIF00P01NSAV1999-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
    <OUTCOND NAME="ZGIF00P01NSVN1000-OK" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="+"/>
    <QUANTITATIVE NAME="QR-GIF00P000" ONFAIL="R" ONOK="R" QUANT="1"/>
</JOB>
```

Comment: Is that really the input data? Because it's not valid XML. The second `JOB` tag isn't closed anywhere, and the `ON` tag in the first is malformed.

Comment: it's just exemple of the format of my xml file ...

Comment: @rouis the point is that it's a _broken_ example, which means that tools designed to manipulate XML will not be able to deal with it properly. You shouldn't be using awk to do this. Try a tool such as xmlstarlet instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that the input data is valid XML, use a proper XML-parsing tool instead of awk for this. Handling XML with awk will result in scripts that break down when the XML format is changed in benign ways, such as inserted newlines or changed order of attributes. Nobody expects their XML-handling tools to break down when such changes occur, and therefore it is *always* better to handle XML with tools that are written for that purpose.

For example, with `xmlstarlet` you could simply write:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//JOB[@JOBNAME="NSVN1QU1"]/@TASKTYPE' -v 'vvvvvv' file.xml
```

Here `//JOB[@JOBNAME="NSVN1QU1"]/@TASKTYPE` is an XPath expression selecting the `@TASKTYPE` attribute of a `JOB` node whose `JOBNAME` attribute is `NSVN1QU1`. The command updates the value of that attribute to the given value `vvvvvv`.

**Addendum:** Another, somewhat more complicated way that will work with every XSLT processor (in the event that xmlstarlet is not available for some reason) is to use the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//JOB[@JOBNAME='NSVN1QU1']/@TASKTYPE">
    <xsl:attribute name="TASKTYPE">
      <xsl:value-of select="'vvvvvv'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Put that in a file, say `transform.xsl`, and use any XSLT processor to do the transformation. For example:

```
xsltproc transform.xsl filename.xml
```

or

```
xalan -xsl transform.xsl -in filename.xml
```

For other utilities, consult their respective man pages.

The way this works is that the

```
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

bit copies the input as it is given unless there's a matching template declared (in which case the template is applied), and the

```
  <xsl:template match="//JOB[@JOBNAME='NSVN1QU1']/@TASKTYPE">
    <xsl:attribute name="TASKTYPE">
      <xsl:value-of select="'vvvvvv'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

template does the same transformation as before under the same conditions as before.

Comment: I have this result:  ./test.sh: line 5: xmlstarlet: command not found

Comment: So...install xmlstarlet.

Comment: If a cant install xmlstarlet do you have other solution please ??

Comment: I added a less succinct way to do the same thing. It'll work with any XSLT processor. I do hope you have one of them available, because otherwise processing XML is going to be very painful.